# Get text value with PHP simple HTML DOM parser

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

How can I get the text value where `<span>Your name:<span>` with the PHP simple HTML DOM parser without children command?

```
<div class="adds-info">
    <span>price:<span>1000000000 </span></span>
    <span>txt1</span>
    <span>Your name:<span>aaa</span></span>
    <span>Phone:<span>02632402210</span></span>
</div>
```

[PHP simple HTML DOM parser api](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm)

Comment: Yes this works in CSS, but i need this in  php simple html dom .

Comment: do you mean?  <span>price:<?php  echo $value; ?></span>

Comment: Apparently, things like `:first-child` are not supported. You can do something like `$simpledomobject->find(".adds-info span span", 1)`, would that help? To print the text, you'd do `echo $simpledomobject->find(".adds-info span span", 1)->innertext;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you defines, i try by this and works

```
$spans = '.adds-info span';
foreach($spans as $n){  
                        if (strpos($n->innertext, "Your name:") !== FALSE) {
                            $name = $n->innertext;
                            $name = str_replace('Your name:', '', $name);
                            echo "Name: " . $name  . "<hr>";
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: There's no way this code works. This has a foreach iterating over a string.

Comment: That isn't different. It's still iterating over a string, which isn't possible...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the HTML in your post is in a variable `$str`, this is fairly straightforward:

```
// Parse the HTML string into a DOM object
$html = str_get_html($str);

// Find the second nested span inside the <div class="adds-info">, then get its parent
$span = $html->find('.adds-info span span', 1)->parent;

// Get the innerhtml of the parent span
$name = $span->innertext;
```

If the number of elements changes, you need to check each one for the text you're looking for...

```
// Get all spans inside the <div class="adds-info">
$spans = $html->find('.adds-info span');

// Loop through each span, looking for "Your name:"
foreach ($spans as $span) {
    if (strpos($span->innerhtml, "Your name:") !== FALSE) {
        $name = $span->innerhtml;
    }
}
```

Comment: I repeated my question with a little change in my expression. i need to get text after [span=Your name] Span value must be equal to [span=Your name] . sorry for my english

Comment: I've updated my answer, but why do you not want to use the children function?

Comment: Not because the number of children varies, i need outertext of <span>Your name:<span> ( AAA )

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of looping through each child span to find the one containing the text "Your name:" and return that span's innerhtml.