# How to get content text of div by simple html dom - php

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I get the bottom html code by `simple dom html` (file_get_html('http://example.com'))

```
<div id="ship" class="fe" data-feature-name="box" data-cel-widget="sox">
 <div class="a-medium b-di">
   <div id="mer-info" class="a-section a-spacing-mini">

    Hello World

     <span class="">          
    </span>   

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

How can I get '**Hello World**" content text?

I tried a lot of things for example bottom text, but that gave me 'NULL'

```
   $html->find('div[id="mer-info"]',0);
   $html->find("div#mer-info");
   $html->find("div#mer-info")->plaintext;
   $html->find('div[id="mer-info"]')->innertext;
   and ...
```

But I got NULL still!

Comment: Please provide your code example. It is not clear how you used `file_get_html()`, and I tested your three approaches and two of them actually work, so the problem might be related to how you retrieved the html.

Comment: @Nima I updated. I get HTML codes with ```file_get_html``` how to access all ```div``` content with ```simple_html_dom.php```

Comment: This question may already have an answer here...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053528/get-text-value-with-php-simple-html-dom-parser

Answer (score 0):

You only passed the second argument (0) to `find` method where you used `div[id="mer-info"]` as selector, which seems not to be recognized by find method. Try the following:

```
require 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html =<<<html
<div id="ship" class="fe" data-feature-name="box" data-cel-widget="sox">
 <div class="a-medium b-di">
   <div id="mer-info" class="a-section a-spacing-mini">

    Hello World

     <span class="">
    </span>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
html;

$dom = str_get_html($html);

$elem = $dom->find('#mer-info', 0);
print $elem->plaintext;
print "\n";

$elem = $dom->find('div#mer-info', 0);
print $elem->plaintext;
```

Comment: Yes, I did, please try it like an external URL. I mean is get the HTML via ```file_get_html``` and after that try, thanks

Comment: Are you sure `file_get_html` is getting correct HTML? That's what i was trying to say in my commend, maybe it is not the problem with how you use `find` method but how you get the html. Please try my code without replacing the `str_get_html` with `file_get_html` to see if it works. If it does, then probably your problem is with `file_get_html` function.

Comment: oops, that was inside a lot of ```div``` tag maybe because of that. how I have to do? that's the child of 8 div, I mean that has 8 parent ```div```